# Power to which 7 is raised to produce a number starting with 2015...

Tags: number-theory

**Q. Is there a power of 7 such that the number produced starts with 2015?**

I am completely stumped and any hints towards the solution would be great, bear in mind this is a question posed to a student in his first year of university I would prefer a hint towards a solution not using any advanced results etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $7^n=2015\ldots$, the $\log_{10}(7^n)\approx m+\log_{10}2015$ for some $m$ (and with "$\approx$" meaning more precisely that $m+\log_{10}2015\le \log_{10}(7^n)<m+\log_{10}2016$). Now use $\log_{10}(7^n)=n\log_{10}7$ and the nontrivial fact that - because $\log_{10}7$ is irrational - the integer multiples of $\log_{10}7$, taken modulo $1$, are dense in the interval $[0,1]$.

The last sentence may be too advanced, so instead of using it to show abstractly the existence of such $n$, we shall go look for it explicitly (being confident from the advanced result that the search will not be futile).
We have
$$\log_{10}2015 = 3.304275\ldots\qquad \log_{10}2016=3.3044905\ldots$$
so we want $n$ such that $n\log_{10}7$ begins after the decimal point *at least* with $304$; more precisely we have to hit an interval of length only $0.000215\ldots$.
So let's get started:
$$\tag1\log_{10}7=0.84509\ldots $$
is way off. But it is somewhat close to $\frac56=0.8333\ldots$ so that we try
$$\tag26\log_{10}7=\star.070588\ldots $$
(I deliberately anonymized the integer part because we can ignore it). Now we are closer to zero, but still much larger than $0.000215\ldots$. The number in $(2)$ is somewhat close to $\frac1{14}$ hence let's see what happens if we multiplyby $14$:
$$\tag314\cdot 6\cdot\log_{10}7=\star.9882\ldots$$
which looks close to $\frac{84}{85}$, so we multiply with $85$:
$$\tag4 85\cdot 14\cdot 6\cdot\log_{10}7=\star.000005701\ldots$$
Wow! What an improvement! This is *way* smaller than our required $0.000215$, hence if we multiply it with an integer so that the result is just above $\star.304275$, it will certainly be below $\star.3044905$,  just as desired.
So we compute $\frac{0.304275}{0.000005701}=53372.2\ldots$ and therefore try
$$ 53373\cdot 85\cdot 14\cdot 6\cdot\log_{10}7=322052682.3043218389548\ldots$$
so that

$$7^{53373\cdot 85\cdot 14\cdot 6}=\underbrace{\color{red}{2015}2170966\ldots}_{322052683\text{ digits}} $$

(This is certainly not the *smallest* possible exponent, but so what?)

Comment: As you mentioned "Log107 is irrational - the integer multiples of log107, taken modulo 1, are dense in the interval [0,1]" is there anything you could possibly direct me to in order to make this more rigorous. Thanks.